# SMT Package Type 30mm x 30mm 80 pin quad flat no-lead package

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, breadboard, prototyping

I have an IC that is 30mm x 30mm x 2.9 mm quad flat package with 80 castellated pins. You can read more about it here: http://simcom.ee/modules/wcdma-hspa/sim5320/

I would like to mount on a breadboard for prototyping, but every adapter I have found online (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/SUNKEE-16-80-adapter-Board-plate/dp/B00AX50Y2G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AX50Y2G)) are all too small. Are there any adapters that can fit this size or do I have to get a custom made PCB made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module has an uncommon shape, which is typical for RF modules like that.  Unless the manufacturers of the module provide a breakout board,  I doubt that you will be able to find an off-the shelf adapter.

Furthermore, this is not simply a case of building a SMT-to-breadboard adapter.
This module outputs an RF signal for GSM and GPS.  You will not be able to run these signals through a breadboard.  Manufacturers of modules like that usually provide development boards.
Look for that.